# Import Error: No module named requests (PokemonGo-Map)

Tags: python, windows, pip, pokemon-go

I have Installed the PokemonGo-Map like this Steps.

[image]

1. Install

   - NodeJS
   - Git
   - Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7
   - Python 2.7
2. Right-click on the Desktop and open "Git Bash".
3. Enter "git clone https://github.com/PokemonGoMap/PokemonGo-Map.git"
4. In the Git Console, enter "cd PokemonGo-Map/" to switch folders.
5. Enter "pip install -r requirements.txt".
6. Now open a command prompt and navigate to our folder.
7. Enter "npm install -g grunt-cli".
8. Enter "npm install".
9. Create a Google-API.
10. Now the following command can be entered into the command prompt: python
     runserver.py -a google -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD -l "LAT, LONG" -st 5
     -H 0.0.0.0 -k API-Key

On my Notebook it works.
But I want to install this Map on my server.
Its an Windows 10 R2 datacenter Server created from Microsoft Azure.
[image]

When I launch 'pip install -r requirements.txt' I received this error:
[image: Install requirements]

After I tried to launch the Map, but received this error.
[image]

Whats wrong?

Comment: Did you use an admin cmd?

Comment: Yes i have an Admin cmd.

Comment: Git console ran as admin too?

Comment: I have now run the git as admin an run the comand again. but it coms the same error.

Comment: Are you sure you installed Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7? I had the exact same issue but it was resolved after installing the compiler.